# Android blackberry playbook application screen size confusion

Tags: android, blackberry, emulation

I am stuck in developing an android app which needs to run in blackberry playbook. First I started developing the app in the Android emulator where I get stuck about the screen size of the emulator. Searching, I found the size of the playbook is 1024 X 600 pixels. What size should I set in the emulator to get the work done? I am designing the layout which will look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The blackberry playbook has a 1024×600 resolution.So you make playbook size! for the small device big resolution will give best resolution!

You can also check on  [Supporting Multiple Screens.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)